# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Address'

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I am using Pandas to insert a title() into the Address column in my csv file so I can directly accurate my csv file without making a temp csv file but it keeps throwing out an error. Please provide your punctilious advice.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('C:\\Users\\Admissions.csv')
df.Address = df.Address.apply(lambda x: x.title())
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Admissions.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Addressupdate.py", line 23, in <module>
    df.Address = df.Address.apply(lambda x: x.title())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2744, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Address'
```

Error:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('C:\\Users\\Admissions.csv')
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.title()
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Admissions.csv', index=False, sep='\t')

File "pandas/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4160)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4024)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13161)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13115)
KeyError: 'Address'
```

Comment: can you try `df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.title()`

Comment: Could you share the contents of `df` after its initial assignment?

Comment: what do you have in `Admissions.csv` ? Edit question and add error message in question, not in comment - it will be more readable.

Comment: @fuglede, the three lines are my code. df is the initial assisgnment.

Comment: firstly post the output from `df.info()` into your question, what is your pandas version? if it's a really old version try `df['Address'] = df['Address']apply(lambda x: x.title())`

Comment: @PLearner: Right, I was interested in seeing the actual contents of the DataFrame (or at least part of it). The code should work (in recent versions of pandas) if `Address` exists as a column.

Comment: I have pandas <0.19.0>.

Comment: The 'Address' is the second column in my csv file...row[1].

Comment: what is `df.columns.tolist()` ? It seems there is some whitespace.

Comment: Where do you see df.columns.tolist()?

Comment: check `print (df.columns.tolist())` after read_csv - get column name to list and check if in name `Address` is no whitespace or some another problem.

Comment: print df.columns.tolist()  .................   ['\xef\xbb\xbf"Permit Number","Address","Street Name","Applicant Name","Contractor Name","SITE_SUBDIVISION","RECORDID"'] I do not know what the letters mean before the "Permit Number". When I open the csv file I do not see those alien letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, you have some strange characters in the column titles in Admissions.csv. What if you rename the columns in Python immediately after reading it?

```
df.columns = ["Permit Number","Address","Street Name","Applicant Name","Contractor Name","SITE_SUBDIVISION","RECORDID"]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, yeah something is up with the csv. You think renaming the columns might do the trick?